# existence of subgroups of different orders

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group of order $60$.Pick out the true statements:

a. $G$ is abelian

b. $G$ has a subgroup of order $30$

c. $G$ has subgroups of order $2$,$3$ and $5$

d. $G$ has subgroups of order $6$, $10$ and $15$

For (a), $G=D_{30}$. This is a non-abelian subgroup . Hence (a) is false.

For (c), by Sylow's Theorem $2$,$3$ and $5$ which are all prime numbers divide $60$ and hence there exists subgroups of order $2$,$3$ and $5$.

Now I am not getting any counter example to show that (b) and (d) are false. Just because I can't prove it, doesn't ensure that it is false.

Comment: Well, what groups of order $60$ are you familiar with?

Comment: d_30,A_5.....??

Comment: any subgroup of index $2$ is normal???

Comment: yes.........normal

Comment: so.. can you conclude b is false?

Comment: Normal  ..then how can i conclude so??

Comment: what do you know about $A_5$??? Heard something like $A_n$ is simple for $n\geq 5$??

Answer (score 2):

For b., you can use the fact that a subgroup of index $2$ is a normal subgroup, and apply that to one of the groups of order $60$ that you know.

For c., you have to be careful when using Sylow's theorems. $60 = 2^2 \times 3\times 5$, i.e the $2$-Sylows are of order $4$, not $2$. There is indeed a group of order $p$ for each prime $p$ diving $60$, but this is known as Cauchy's theorem.

For d., use c.

Comment: why down vote??

Comment: There are versions of Sylow's Theorems that state that $G$ has a subgroup of order $q$ for any prime power $q$ dividing $|G|$ - perhaps the OP was using this.

Answer (score 0):

Results:

- any subgroup of index 2 is normal... This should tell you $b$ is false...
- any group of even order contains an element of order $2$.. this along with sylow theorem should tell you $c$ is true. As pointed out by Antonie your justification is not sufficient.
- any group of order $15$ is cyclic... This should tell you $d$ is false...